# open own app when car audio media button pressed when it connected via bluetooth

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I need to open my app when car's audio media button pressed,
When I connect my phone to car audio and after pressing media/voice/speek button it opens google assistance by default, I need to open my own app on this button pressed, How to bypass google assistant and open my app.

What code need to add in to my manifest or java class?
Any tutorial or codelink is available to refer.

Comment: this may not be possible. the press of that button would have to send a broadcast which your phone would receive. the only way to really send a broadcast from that button press is by hacking your way into the software of your car.

Comment: There is app called bluetooth launcher by which we can change default launch app on media button if we select myapp on media button launch then it open my app from next time. I want to know how it works?